# How to iterate through a list of objects from api and render it to jsx page React functional component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get a list of array items from an api response using useEffect, as a result I'm getting a list of objects. I want to convert that using Objects.key() method, but when I iterate through it, values won't be printed on view page. The response keeps on returning the call from api response.

API CALL

```
 export function getServicesById(facility_id) {     
  return axios
        .get(`${baseURL}patients/appointments/1`)
        .then((response) => {
            if(response.status===200){
                // console.log(response.data)
                return response
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('error', error)
            return error
        });
    }
```

useEffect to get response data

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getServicesById()
      .then((res) => {
        setResponseData(res.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    // console.log('data is', newResponseData);
  }, [responseData, setResponseData]);
```

Converting objects to array items

```
 const newResponseData = Object.keys(responseData).reduce((array, key) => {
    return [...array, { key: responseData[key] }];
  }, []);
```

Jsx page where I'm rendering the data

```
<TableBody>              
  {newResponseData &&
    newResponseData.map((serv, index) => (
    <TableRow key={index}>
       <TableCell align="left" data-label="Action">
           <Field
              name="status"
              component={renderSelectInput}
              variant="outlined"
              size="small"
              className="fileds"
              inputClass="sm-filed"
            >
            <MenuItem selectedValue="progress">
               In progress
             </MenuItem>
             <MenuItem value="closed">
              Closed
             </MenuItem>
            </Field>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell data-label="Id">{serv.id}</TableCell>
            <TableCell data-label="Patient name">{serv.patient_name}</TableCell>
            <TableCell data-label="Test Name">{serv.test_name}</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      ))}
   </TableBody>
```

Comment: You are iterating the mapped `newResponseData` array. What isn't working? Can you describe that in a bit more detail? Potential issue I see is the mapped objects have only a `key` key.

Comment: Values are not displayed on the page, I'm getting a count of table rows with the amount of records I have in db but they are not displayed on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are using an `useEffect` dependency that the effect updates:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getServicesById()
    .then((res) => {
      setResponseData(res.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}, [responseData, setResponseData]);
```

`responseData` is updated by the effect, and when updated will trigger another rerender and the effect will run again. You likely only want to fetch the data once when the component mounts.

Another potential issue I see is that the `newResponseData` array has objects with only a `key` key.

```
const newResponseData = Object.keys(responseData).reduce((array, key) => {
  return [...array, { key: responseData[key] }];
}, []);
```

But in the render you are attempting to access `id`, `patient_name`, and `test_name` properties. These are undefined since `{ key: responseData[key] }` hasn't any of these properties.

## Solution

Remove the `useEffect` dependencies so the effect runs once on component mount. Since I also think you meant to compute an array of the object values from `responseData` to map in your UI, you can do this once ***before*** sending the data to state.

```
useEffect(() => {
  getServicesById()
    .then((res) => {
      const data = Object.values(res.data)
      setResponseData(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}, []);
```

Then just map your `responseData` state:

```
<TableBody>              
  {responseData && responseData.map((serv, index) => (
    <TableRow key={index}>
       <TableCell align="left" data-label="Action">
           <Field
              name="status"
              component={renderSelectInput}
              variant="outlined"
              size="small"
              className="fileds"
              inputClass="sm-filed"
            >
            <MenuItem selectedValue="progress">
               In progress
             </MenuItem>
             <MenuItem value="closed">
              Closed
             </MenuItem>
            </Field>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell data-label="Id">{serv.id}</TableCell>
            <TableCell data-label="Patient name">{serv.patient_name}</TableCell>
            <TableCell data-label="Test Name">{serv.test_name}</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      ))}
   </TableBody>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answer by Drew Reese, Please remove responseData from useEffect params as you are using setResponseData inside it and useEffect gets triggered on every state change :

```
useEffect(() => {
    getServicesById()
      .then((res) => {
        setResponseData(res.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, [setResponseData]);
```